# How is this settings popup created?

Tags: ios, swift

I really like the way the settings are shown on the Books app and am trying to figure out how replicated it.

[Screenshot of Books app with settings shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2pnk.jpg)

Is this an .actionsheet that is somehow moved to show up under the Settings image or a container view that shows up on tap or something else? I'm still at level noob with a basic app and would like to implement this.

Comment: This looks like a custom made pop up that is a `UIStackView`

Answer (score 1):

It is iOS default presentation style for controllers. It's called `UIPopOverPresentationController`. Here's a [good article](https://www.appcoda.com/presentation-controllers-tutorial/) on presentation controllers. After that you might want to create two to three cells for your options in a `UITableView` and add that as controller for the popover from your storyboard.
You can also change the popover arrow pointing location and direction which you might need when you want to support your app for iPad as well. :)

```
@IBAction func actionWasTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopOverVC")
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    let popover: UIPopoverPresentationController = vc.popoverPresentationController!
    popover.barButtonItem = sender
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: updated the syntax thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can done with a-lot of way  , you can just create by 
UIView work as **background** with custom subview (**PopOverMenu**) done with **UIBezierPath** to draw this arrow with corner radius view

upon this pop over you can create MultiSection tableview or collection View or any

1. Background is add as SubView to `UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.addSubview(background)`
2. Background have tab gesture to dismiss when tab on background
3. some closure to bring back data that user select it

Comment: None of this necessary.

Comment: i don't mention any necessary , just one solution from others @rmaddy

Comment: But you propose an overly complex, unnecessary solution. iOS provides a simple, standard way to present a view controller as a popover. Please see the answers to the linked duplicate.

Comment: ok, thanks , any notes from you is appreciated